# How to unmarshal proto with scanner using net.Conn?

Tags: go, tcp, protocol-buffers

I have setup a go server to receive data from a client. Have faced the issue attempting to unmarshal the object. Am I doing this the wrong way? It was working well with text.

This is my code currently:

```
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)

for {
    ok := scanner.Scan()

    if !ok {
        break
    }
    request := &protoBuf.Request{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(scanner.Bytes(), request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unmarshaling error: ", err)
    }
}
}
```

Error message:

```
2019/10/02 19:24:29 unmarshaling error: proto: protoBuf.Request: 
illegal tag 0 (wire type 2)
```

Comment: Are you trying to emulate grpc? This can be done easily with a grpc service. That said, scanner reads line-delimited input. Protobuf is a binary protocol, it is not line-delimited.